# How to or in a ruby on rails Mongodb query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rails-console

I need to perform this sql query in rails console (I'm using mongodb):

```
SELECT * FROM Member WHERE name='x' OR age='42'
```

Comment: What about reading some docs ? Or using google ?

Comment: Did that, didn't find anything useful. What about answering my question?

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there that show you how to do this. Official guides and SO-questions. If you haven't found anything, you clearly haven't been trying hard enough. Also - it is appreciated to show what solutions you have tried yourself already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mongoid I use 'any_of'. This should work:

```
Member.any_of({:name => x, :age => 42})
```

Also here's a link to some other queries you can use with mongoid. I don't see these in their main doc page:

http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_of

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the [Active Record Query Interface RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), it'll answer your question, and probably teach you some other things you don't already know.